# HTML to PDF convertion issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, itext

I have two problems when converting HTML (MVC Razor page) to PDF with non UTF8 characters.

1) Generating PDF with Chinese characters
2) Whenever I enable the addition of CSS files I always get exception " Input string was not in a correct format." But when I comment my own CSS and use the GetDefaultCSS, the error doesn't show up and the PDF is being generated but the chinese characters appear as question marks (?)

Here is the code:

```
public static byte[] BuildPDFContent<T>(T model, string template, ControllerContext context)
{
    CoreController controller = (CoreController)context.Controller;
    var html = controller.RenderRazorViewToString(template, model);
    MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(html));
    MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();

    string fontAwesomeCss = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Content/css/font-awesome.min.css");
    string bootstrapCss = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Content/css/bootstrap.css");
    string siteCss = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Content/css/site.css");
    Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
    doc.SetMargins(doc.LeftMargin, doc.RightMargin, 35, 0);
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, msOutput);
    doc.Open();
    var tagProcessors = (DefaultTagProcessorFactory)Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
    tagProcessors.RemoveProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG); // remove the default processor
    tagProcessors.AddProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG, new CustomImageTagProcessor()); // use our new processor
    CssFilesImpl cssFiles = new CssFilesImpl();
    cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(new FileStream(fontAwesomeCss, FileMode.Open)));
    cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(new FileStream(bootstrapCss, FileMode.Open)));
    cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(new FileStream(siteCss, FileMode.Open)));
    //cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCSS());
    StyleAttrCSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles);
    var hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(new UnicodeFontFactory()));
    hpc.SetAcceptUnknown(true).AutoBookmark(true).SetTagFactory(tagProcessors); // inject the tagProcessors
    HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, pdfWriter));
    IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
    XMLParser xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);
    xmlParse.Parse(msInput);
    doc.Close();
    return msOutput.ToArray();
```

}

```
private class UnicodeFontFactory : FontFactoryImp
{
    private static readonly string FontPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts),
      "arialuni.ttf");

    private readonly BaseFont _baseFont;

    public UnicodeFontFactory()
    {
        _baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(FontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

    }

    public override Font GetFont(string fontname, string encoding, bool embedded, float size, int style, BaseColor color,
      bool cached)
    {
        return new Font(_baseFont, size, style, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `UnicodeFontFactory` actually load a font that supports Chinese characters and are you referencing that font specifically by name in your CSS?

Comment: Yup it does support Chinese characters but regarding your second question there was no referencing happened for that font by name in the CSS.  Can you describe it further a sample implementation perhaps?  I know the way to reference a font through CSS but I just want to make sure we are on the same page. Thanks.

Comment: You are bundling different errors in one question. It's not easy to assess whether you have a font problem, an encoding problem or a problem with faulty CSS. Using wrong CSS could cause iTextSharp to use the wrong font.

Comment: I know it's been a very long time since I posted this because I don't usually post and monitor in stackoverflow but thanks for the answer.  As far as I remember we set the regions of the server to chinese settings and that worked.